# Dialogflow Web Demo Audio

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a Dialogflow agent with the Web Demo integration enabled.  When using the Web Demo I can interact with the agent by talking and typing.  However the response is always text only, even if the interaction was by voice.

I would like to hear the response. Is there a setting somewhere that I need to enable audio in the response?  Or is this simply not possible?

Comment: Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: No unfortunately not

Answer (score 0):

Use the speechSynthesis API.

[enter link description here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SpeechSynthesis/speak)